# javascript bug using setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid

I have this program which tells you your reaction time, and it works fine, but if you run the program and click the start button twice, instead of once, the background turns red right away, instead of waiting for the set interval. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("reactionTester");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var startTime;
var scoreContainer = document.getElementById("p");
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
var counter = 0;

function init() {
    var startInterval /*in milliseconds*/ = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 1000;
    setTimeout(startTimer, startInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
    startTime = Date.now();
    document.body.appendChild(css);
    css.innerHTML = "html{background-color: red;}";
    if (counter = 1) {
        p1 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        p1.parentNode.removeChild(p1);
    }
}

function stopTimer() {
    if (startTime) {
        var stopTime = Date.now();
        var dif = stopTime - startTime;
        alert("Your time is " + dif + " ms");
        startTime = null;
        css.innerHTML = null;
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        p.innerHTML = dif;
        counter = 0;
        counter++;
    } else {
        alert("don't trick me");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<div class="tableRow">
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="init()">
</div>
<div class="tableRow">
<input type="button" id="reactionTester" onclick="stopTimer()" value="stop">
</div>
<div id="p">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How do you know that the second click isn't simply resulting in a very short interval? Your code can result in an interval as small as zero milliseconds.

Comment: Also you don't cancel the previously-set timer when the "init" function runs.

Comment: Because it happens every single time that I try it. It could be a coincidence but I highly doubt it since it happens as soon as I do the second click.

Comment: Do you know how I would go about canceling it?

Comment: Nvm you're right the problem is that multiple timers start.

Comment: `setTimeout` returns a value. Save that value in a variable, then pass it to `clearTimeout()` when you want to start a new timer. (It doesn't hurt anything to call `clearTimeout()` with a bogus value, so you can just always call it.)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 (potential) problems here:

1. Every time `init()` is run it resets `startTime` to `Date.now()`. So when stopTimer runs, it runs only against the latest click time.
2. init can set an interval of 0ms which may be intended...

To fix the first problem you can do one of a few things, but the most straightforward is to cancel the first timeout by getting a reference then later clearing it:

```
var timeoutId;

function init(){
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(func, delay);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you possibly explain which parts of that code I would need to change for my code, like what would I put in the delay? What does the delay variable delay?

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the timers in a variable so you can reset it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var button = document.getElementById("reactionTester");
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var startTime;
var scoreContainer = document.getElementById("p");
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
var counter = 0;
var timer = null;

function init() {
    var startInterval /*in milliseconds*/ = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) * 1000;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(startTimer, startInterval);
}

function startTimer() {
    startTime = Date.now();
    document.body.appendChild(css);
    css.innerHTML = "html{background-color: red;}";
    if (counter = 1) {
        p1 = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
        p1.parentNode.removeChild(p1);
    }
}

function stopTimer() {
    if (startTime) {
        var stopTime = Date.now();
        var dif = stopTime - startTime;
        alert("Your time is " + dif + " ms");
        startTime = null;
        css.innerHTML = null;
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        p.innerHTML = dif;
        counter = 0;
        counter++;
    } else {
        alert("don't trick me");
    }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form">
<div class="tableRow">
<input type="button" value="start" id="start" onclick="init()">
</div>
<div class="tableRow">
<input type="button" id="reactionTester" onclick="stopTimer()" value="stop">
</div>
<div id="p">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```